# Angular 2 cookie authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, cookies

I am writing some integration between Angular 2(not a big expert in JS) and Rails 4.2. On Rails side I am using devise for authentication. The thing is when I am requesting to sign in user, `Set-Cookie` header is returned in response. But then, when I am trying to request any authentication-required resource `Cookie` header has value of `"Set-Cookie=null"`(like there is no value of `Set-Cookie`?). Here's how it's done:

session.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SessionService{
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'})
    private createSessionUrl = 'http://localhost:3002/users/sign_in';

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) { }

    create(email: string, password: string): Promise<User>{
        return this.http.post(this.createSessionUrl, JSON.stringify({user:{email: email, password: password}}),
            { headers: this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as User)
            .catch(this.handleError)
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

statistics.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions }    from '@angular/http';
import { Statistics }       from '../models/statistics.models'

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class StatisticsService{
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'})
    private statisticsUrl = 'http://localhost:3002/statistics';

    constructor(
        private http: Http
    ) {}

    show(): Promise<Statistics>{
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });
        return this.http.get(this.statisticsUrl, options)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Statistics)
            .catch(this.handleError)
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

As far as I know, `let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true });`
should include proper Cookie in request.

If there is any extra info required, please write in comments.

Answer (score 2):

your question is quite old, but I hope it helps anyway. I stumbled about that problem as well and wished to find your question answered. Now I take care of that.

I think you forgot the `withCredentials` option in the POST request of your `session.service.ts`. As you send a request with credentials (email and password) and you expect the response to set a cookie, you should tell the http-service about that:

```
return this.http.post(
  this.createSessionUrl, 
  JSON.stringify({user:{email: email, password: password}}),
  { headers: this.headers, withCredentials: true }
)
```

Now the cookie should be stored by the browser and the next statistics request should contain the correct cookie.

Does this work?

Cheers,
Friedrich